# Display query in a div or custom location?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How could I have my database connection information at the top of my page but have the query separate from the code but still related so that I could have the print or echo displaying the retrieved images in a Div that I could place anywhere on my site?

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');
$q = "SELECT badge1 FROM user_badges WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}' LIMIT 1";
$r = mysql_query($q);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$badge1 = $row['badge1'];

if($badge1 == "unlocked") {
 print "image if user has unlocked the badge";
  } else {
 print "image if user hasn't unlocked the badge";
}

?>
```

I would like to have the above **if** and **else** statements placed in a div so I could position the images printed from the query anywhere on my site.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways. Here is one example:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');
$q = "SELECT badge1 FROM user_badges WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}' LIMIT 1";
$r = mysql_query($q);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$badge1 = $row['badge1'];
?> 

//Break out of PHP and add any HTML elements you want

<div id="whatever">

<?php
if($badge1 == "unlocked") {
    print "image if user has unlocked the badge";
} else {
    print "image if user hasn't unlocked the badge";
}
?>
</div>
```

p.s. Check your PDO. It's mixed with old `MySQL_` stuff

Comment: Worked great thank you so much! also thanks for noticing the old msql_ ! I will take care of that :)